Which cards use −5 V and −12 V in IBM PC compatible systems?
IBM PC power supplies have output voltages of +5 V, −5 V, +12 V, and −12 V. Among these, −5 V and −12 V are not commonly used in modern systems.
I am testing an old AT power supply with a multimeter, and while the +5 V and +12 V outputs are normal, the −5 V and −12 V outputs are about 20% lower than expected, measuring −4 V and −10 V, respectively. Although this power supply can still be used for computers without major issues, I am curious about which cards might be affected by the lower output voltages.
Based on your experience, could you tell me which cards use −5 V and −12 V?

Are you putting a real load on those outputs, not just a multimeter (switching power supplies will not always show actual voltages without current flowing). If so, then I would be wondering just how much longer the power supply will actually function for...

I don't see how it is relevant what ChatGPT said. Also the power supply might be fine as it needs load to work properly. So is this about the power supply having funny outputs as per your measurements or about a list of ISA cards using -12V and -5V as these two seem unrelated?

How old is the power supply? Have you tested the smoothing capacitors? These can go partial short after a long time and may need to be reformed or replaced. If there is a capacitor issue I'd advise against using the power supply (even for just +5, +12) until this is resolved.

Vogons has a list of ISA cards relying on -5V; only one of them is not a sound card (the 3Com EL16/TP network interface card). There weren’t that many cards requiring -5V however; Vogons only lists seven (but that’s not exhaustive).
-12V was more commonly used, notably by sound cards (often producing -5V from -12V), and as you mention, RS-232 cards. The RS-232 protocol requires voltage levels switching from positive to negative n volts, with n between 5 and 15; on the PC, ISA serial cards commonly used +12V and -12V. Even PCI serial cards would use -12V. Some graphics adapters also used -12V. See this VCFed thread on -5V and -12V for details.

Minor correction, RS-232 output must provide at least +/-5V into worst case load defined, and the input must accept down to +/-3V as valid values for noise margin.

I recall a modem back in the day, I think it was Zoom brand, which required -5 to function, which meant that it wouldn't work in a Tandy 1000 without adding a -5 supply.

@Justme I'm not sure PCs ever used anything other than 12v on serial. That's part of why homebrew knock-off TI-calc link cables used Zener diodes to reduce the voltage, or operated on a parallel port.

@davolfman Define a PC? Many laptops used something in the style of MAX232 with built-in charge pumps. So it sort of makes internal supplies irrelevant if RS-232 interface supplies are made locally from say 5V. And the Zeners were used to clamp the voltage, so if it were +/-5 only, the zener does not need to clamp. I also built both types of cables, and software for them on PC.

Nobody can give you a full list.
But what you heard is true.
Most RS-232 cards use -12V, and some sound cards use it for negative supply for audio circuits, either directly or making -5V onboard. Such as early Sound Blaster cards.
Some sound cards use the -5V directly instead of the -12V and therefore don't work in systems where -5V is missing. This makes some later Sound Blaster cards to not work.
And if you are measuring the negative output voltages without any load, don't expect them to be correct, they are out of regulation with no load and may work perfectly when the required minimum load is applied.

Additionally, some power supplies are designed in such a way that increasing load on +5 will cause the voltages on other supplies to increase, so if nothing is being drawn from +5 that could cause other voltages to read below spec.  Rather than having a separate transformer and driver circuitry for each voltage, some supplies will use different windings of a shared transformer for different voltages, adjust the amount of power going into it to regulate the +5 output, and let the other voltages fall where they will.

Any card using DRAM in the 80s would need +12V and -5V for the DRAM power supplies. Video cards fall into this category.
